# Separate Thread on GlassFish server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, service, glassfish

I'm doing my graduation project, and have run into a dilemma here.
I need to make an application that generates PDFs and emails them to people on a schedule defined by data in the database.
I'm working for a company with this project, and we already have a GlassFish application server that we use. It would be best if the entire solution is delivered in one package, as it is now.
Client with webstart
Web Application etc. is all in one package

My new service needs to run on a separate thread, generate reports and send them out on emails. From what I can read on the web, running your own threads in an application server as GlassFish is highly discouraged, so it sounds like I need to make my own separate application.

Can this really be? What are your comments, and what are the best practices for this?

Comment: What is the best practice for understanding your question :-) ? confusing with *Client with webstart Web Application etc. is all in one package* , *My new service needs to run on a separate thread*

Comment: I guess I could have made it more clear.
Everything is uploaded to the GlassFish server in one WAR file. Everything from the server logic to the client is in that file, it would be nice to implement this, this way too...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**@Schedule**

If you are using Ejb 3.1 (glassfish 3.x), you may use the @Schedule annotation to have the container invoke a method in a specified interval or at a given calendar time. Allowing you to avoid handling threads in your own code

[Read about ejb 3.1 timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html)

```
@Stateless
public class LabbBean {

    @EJB
    WorkerEjb workerEjb;

    @Schedule(second="*/5", minute="*",hour="*", persistent=false)
    public void myMethod() {
        for (all jobs found in db){
            workerEjb.workerMethod(job);    
        }
    }
}

@Stateless
public class WorkerEjb {
    @Asynchronous
    public void workerMethod(job) {
        //Send emails
    }
}
```

If you wanted to do the work in separate threads, the @Schedule annotated method could call a worker-ejb with the worker-method annotated as @Asynchronous

**@Timeout**

I just realised you wanted the schedule to be initiated from the database. An option the would be to initiate a bunch of timers programmatically using a @Singleton ejb with @Startup annotation. The timeout annotated method would be called in separate threads if some timers run out at the same time.

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class LabbBean {
    @Resource
    protected TimerService timerService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        //Init your timers from the data in the database here
        for (all your timers) {
            TimerConfig config = new TimerConfig();
            config.setInfo("timer1");
            config.setPersistent(false);

            ScheduleExpression schedule = new ScheduleExpression();
            schedule.dayOfMonth(10);
            schedule.minute(2);
            timerService.createCalendarTimer(schedule, config);
        }
    }

    //method called when timeout occurs
    @Timeout
    public void timeoutHandler(Timer timer) {
        String name = timer.getInfo().toString();
        System.out.println("Timer name=" + name);
    }
}
```

Comment: The ideal would be that I could make sub Threads to spread out the work of the heavy work.
So the main thread that listens for scheduled tasks, is ready to take on a new task.
How would you solve that?

Comment: Added some alternatives you can try out.

Comment: Thanks alot for your great answers, while your way seems like the best way, it shows me that it isn't a good idea to let this application live inside GlassFish. I need to make a separate application for this.

Comment: Im not following, an application (.war) deployed on glassfish is 'perfectly' suited to do this task.

Comment: I want to be able to distribute these heavy tasks to multiple clients, so its not only one server that does the job.
You might argue that it should be a webapplication and through that I can expand it, but in my head it doesn't fit into the server we are running now, which contains and runs all logic. It will be too heavily loaded.

And while I do believe your suggestion is very good, I'm not experienced enough to see the complete benefits of this. It still doesn't solve my other issues, like controlling the tasks.

Comment: I understand, someone would prolly suggested you setup a jboss/glassfish cluster then, but you might get something up an running faster by doing it as a separate client. But i would still use something like above to tell one of the multiple clients to start doing some work

Comment: I can't completely map it out how you think I should do it, but what I've decided is, that I will make a separate library, that has this functionality to generate PDFs, and in the meanwhile I'm getting a book on EJB and J2EE and digging into it.
But it might, as you say, come to the conclusion that I should just implement a client, as it won't be needed to often to send tasks to multiple clients, and therefor I should first implement that when it is needed.

Although I still need to figure out the best way to implement this for future development.

Comment: j2ee is the old tech, try looking at java ee 6: Here is the 'official' tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/